# Realm Sync Not Updating SwiftUI View After Observe is Fired

Tags: ios, swiftui, realm

I am having issues with Realm, which is not causing my View to update. I have a checkbox in a List and when I click on the checkbox, I want to update the isCompleted to true. This part is working and it updates the isCompleted property in Realm Sync (MongoDB Atlas). The problem is that the view never re-renders again.

Here is code for my TaskCellView which updates the isCompleted.

```
struct TaskCellView: View {
    
    var task: Task
    let realmManager = RealmManager.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print(Self._printChanges())
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: task.isCompleted ? "checkmark.square": "square")
                .onTapGesture {
                    try! realmManager.realm.write {
                        task.isCompleted.toggle()
                    }
                }
            Text(task.title)
        }
    }
}
```

In my RealmManager I have setupObservers which fires and assigns the new tasks to the tasks property.

```
 private func setupObservers() {
        let observableTasks = realm.objects(Task.self)
        notificationToken = observableTasks.observe { [weak self] _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(observableTasks)
                self?.tasks = observableTasks
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in my ContentView I use the following code to send the tasks to the TodoListView.

```
 if let tasks = realmManager.tasksArray {
                    let _ = print("INSIDE IF")
                    let _ = print(tasks.count)
                    TodoListView(tasks: tasks)
                }
```

I have checked and the print lines are getting printed but the body of the TodoListView is never executed.

**TodoListView**

```
struct TodoListView: View {
    
    let tasks: [Task]
   
    var pendingTasks: [Task] {
       // tasks.where { $0.isCompleted == false }
        tasks.filter { !$0.isCompleted }
    }
    
    var completedTasks: [Task] {
        tasks.filter { $0.isCompleted }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print(Self._printChanges())
        List {
            ForEach(Sections.allCases, id: \.self) { section in
                Section {
                    ForEach(section == .pending ? pendingTasks: completedTasks, id: \._id) { task in
                        TaskCellView(task: task) 
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text(section.rawValue)
                }
            }
        }.listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

I know it is a lot of code and but maybe someone can see the problem. So even though the checkbox is checked and the Realm database is updated and observe is fired and the tasks are updated to reflect the isCompleted new states. The TodoListView is never re-rendered.

Comment: There isn't anything in your code to let SwiftUI know that the `body` needs to be reloaded. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)  you need a wrapper of some kind. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @loremipsum 100% agree... Along those lines, the code does include `setupObservers` which *could* be used to update the UI on object changes but the event is totally ignored in that function (as-is) and there are no UI update calls. OP, you either need to leverage that observer to update the UI *or* a better choice is to use Realms [@ObservedResults](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/#views-and-observed-objects) property which queries a Realm collection and any object changes automatically result in a redraw of the view.

Comment: @Jay ObservedResults property wrapper does not work when using Realm sync.

Comment: @MaryDoe Hmm. I wasn't aware of that and have it implemented in several apps. In fact, here's a tutorial from the Realm folks that uses Sync, SwiftUI and ObservedResults throughout the app. A quote is *The Realm/SwiftUI integration means that the UI will automatically refresh whenever a new chat message is added to the (sync'd) Realm*. The code implementation to automatically refresh the view when there is a new sync'd chat is `@ObservedResults(Chatster.self) var chatsters`. Perhaps that's a different implementation that what you're referring to?

Comment: Thanks @Jay! You are correct. I was wrong. It is supported.